# How can I query another document in different collection after callback with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I search for another document in another collection after receiving results?

For example, I have a large collection called `Posts` and another large collection called `Users`.

Each user can create multiple posts, and other users can only view these posts if they are friends with them or following them. Here is an example of a `User`:

```
{
   _id: 1234,
   name: "Jack",
   username: 'jack',
   friends: [9439, 4957, 2847]
   followers: [9111, 5746, 6576],
   following: [2121, 4382]
}
```

And here is an example of a `Post`:

```
{
    _id: 2948,
    text: "Hello World",
    postedBy: 4957
}
```

Since the above is `postedBy` user `4957`, and the above example user, `Jack`, is friends with user `4957`, he should receive this post back.

I'm unsure how to approach this due to how new I am with MongoDB, although I assume that an aggregate pipeline would probably be required. I'm guessing it would need to search for posts, get the `postedBy`, check if it exists within the logged in users `friends` or `following` array, then continue onto the next post. I will only be returning a limit of 20 posts per request.

I cannot use embedded documents since both models can change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

try this query , if you want to use query from one collection to another collection in mongodb use $lookup

this query return user colection with friends post

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
{
      $unwind: "$friends"
   },
   {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "post",
          localField: "friends",
          foreignField: "postedBy",
          as: "friendsPost"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "friendsPost": { $ne: [] } }
   }
])
```

this query return output like this

```
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1234,
            "name" : "Jack",
            "username" : "jack",
            "friends" : 4957,
            "followers" : [9111,5746,6576],
            "following" : [2121, 4382],
            "friendsPost" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : 2948,
                    "text" : "Hello World",
                    "postedBy" : 4957
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```